# Is there any good examples for molecule roles that uses kvm? so far getting {'lint': ['must be of string type']} error

Tags: ansible, molecule

I've being trying to run find good repositories or examples of using molecule with kvm. But so far all of them gets this.

{'lint': ['must be of string type']}

I have no clue how to fix this. Like this

```
---
dependency:
  name: galaxy
driver:
  name: docker
lint:
  name: yamllint
platforms:
  - name: instance
    image: centos:7
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  lint:
    name: ansible-lint
verifier:
  name: testinfra
  lint:
    name: flake8
```

Comment: At the very least, `driver: {name: docker}` suggest you did not initialize your role/scenario with the kvm driver... See `molecule init role --help` and `molecule init scenario --help`.

Comment: It looks like you are running with molecule >=3 but you're having a molecule <3 YAML file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error is because your molecule has been updated to version 3 while your test code is still with version 2.
For version 3, use

```
lint: |
  ansible-lint
```

Molecule 3 allows multiple linting tools at the same time, and you can specify them as array.